# I need to turn a comma-separated string into an array list and then calculate the average of those scores

Tags: java, arrays, integer

I am trying to take the code inputs that I have and turn them into an int array list so that I can use them to calculate the average score but I'm not sure on how to do this. Also when it comes to the scores the inputs can range from 1-5, so one student could have 3 scores and the next could have 5 and so on. This is the code I have so far.

My main question is how do I take my list inputs and turn them into separate array integers?

```
//data declarations and initalizations
    final int MAX_STUDENTS = 12;
    final int MAX_SCORE = 5;

    //data declarations
    double avg; //average total for all students
    int numStudents; //number of students 1-12
    double totalAvgStu = 0.0; //
    int num;
    String stuScores = " "; //student score 1-5

    //array declarations and inistiations
    int [] score = new int[MAX_SCORE]; // score from input range between 1-5
    double [] avgScores = new double[MAX_STUDENTS]; //avg total of score for one student
    String [] testScores = new String[MAX_STUDENTS];
    String [] array1 = new String[MAX_SCORE]; 

    //user inputs for number of students
    numStudents = UtilsKS.readInt("Enter number of students: ", false);                                

    //while loop for correct input of students
    while (numStudents <= 0 || numStudents > 12) { 
        System.out.print("ERROR: must be 1-12, ");

        numStudents = UtilsKS.readInt("Enter number of students: ", false);
    }

    // user input for student score using a for loop
    for (int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++) {
        stuScores = UtilsKS.readString("Enter comma-separated test score for student " + (i+1) + ": ", false);

    }

    //for loop for arrays
    for (int i=0; i<avgScores.length; i++) {
        totalAvgStu += avgScores[i];

    }

    //outputs
    String header = "average score1 score2 score3 score4 score5";
    System.out.println("\n" + header);                                                                                  
    System.out.println("\nAvg for all students = " + totalAvgStu/avgScores.length);

    //initializing testscore to = what scores are inputed per student
    for (int t=0; t<numStudents; t++) {
        testScores[t] = stuScores;
    }
```

Comment: You've posted requirements and code but have asked no *specific* question. We're not going to do the code for you of course, but we can answer questions. So please fix this so that we can know how to help you.

Comment: There's a lot of code going on here. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Sorry I added in my main problem, I'm new to using this. I know you have to use .split() and integer.parseInt() somehow but I don't understand how?

Comment: Also look at [this Google search](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=java+comma+separated+string+to+integer+array+site:http:%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F) for other similar questions and answers on this site.

Comment: thanks those actually helped!

Comment: @Kathryn: they were meant to help.

Answer (score 3):

```
Arrays.stream("1,2,3,4,5".split(",")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).average();
```

I suggest considering my compact solution. That returns `OptionalDouble`. `getAsDouble()` will return you the result if you firstly check it by `isPresent()` to avoid `NoSuchElementException`.

---

EDIT:

I don't like to write massive pieces of code with long variable names, but I made the exception for you to better understanding.

```
String commaSeparatedString = "1,2,3,4,5";
String[] numbers = commaSeparatedString.split(",");
Stream<String> stringStream = Arrays.stream(numbers);
IntStream intStream = stringStream.mapToInt(value -> Integer.parseInt(value));
OptionalDouble average = intStream.average();
System.out.println(average.isPresent() ? 
                     "average = " + average.getAsDouble() : 
                     "stream is empty!")
```

Comment: Ah yes, the Java 8 way to do it. 1+

Comment: I'm still a bit new to coding so I'm a little confused

Comment: Arrays is imported from java.util.* :) in case ' just to mention it.

Comment: Dude, I want to learn how to use `::` Where can I refer ? pls tell ! @Andrew

Comment: @TilakMadichetti, look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html)

Comment: @Kathryn, I tried to explain it more detailed

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a sample input and output?
Also an easy(hacky) way would be to intialize 2 variables temp and sum. Parse the string using the comma. Store the value in the temp and add to sum. Store a counter for number of times youve done these steps. Divide sum by counter to get average.